# WP-E Commerce: How to let user leave a personal message/instruction with each product from the products page

Tags: plugin-wp-e-commerce

This is my first question here. I've Googled and searched here but didn't find the answer or any useful instruction. I'm using `wp-e commerce plugin` for the first time.

My question is: How can I let a user add a personal message/instruction from the product page in `wp-e commerce plugin` using a textarea. [Like this site](http://giftsylhet.com/), I want to let the user the ability to add `Add special instruction` with every products from the home/products page. Hope someone can help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This functionality is already built-in to WP e-commerce; however it's defined at the product level not globally.

To enable this for a given product on the product edit page go to 'Advanced Settings' -> 'Personalisation Options' and enable 'Users can personalize this Product by leaving a message on single product page'